# A question about direct sums of subspaces...

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $W_1$ be a subspace of a finite dimensional vector space $V$. Prove that there exists a subspace $W_2\subset V$ such that $V=W_1\oplus W_2$.

### EDIT$^1$:

This may be of use here:

[image]
[image]

---

What does
$$ W_1 \cap W_2 = \{0\}$$
even mean? The zero vector is the only thing shared in common by the two subset?

Comment: I don't see how this "could mean various things". Can you elaborate on where you think the ambiguity is?

Comment: $W_1$ could be the set $\{0\}$, and so could $W_2$, right?

Comment: In that case, if $V$ is not trivial, then $W_1 + W_2 \neq V$.

Comment: I mean it could be, so it's hard to generalize, right?

Comment: Your example is difficult to generalize, yes.  The question is still clear.  You can prove it by starting with a basis for $W_2$.

Comment: The question is asking you to show that, given any set $W_1$, you can find some set $W_2$ such that $V=W_1\oplus W_2$. For example, if $W_1=\{0\}$ then $W_2=V$ gives you the desired result.

Comment: Why not $W_1$??

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you familiar with the definition of intersection, and with vector subspaces?

Comment: To what are you referring to?

Comment: I'm not sure what any of your questions are asking, to be honest. I think you should review the definitions of the terms and symbols in the question. BTW, you are correct that $W_1\cap W_2=\{0\}$ means that the only thing shared by the two subspaces is the zero vector.

Comment: @Trancot Your question is asking you to prove that given *any* subspace $W_1$ of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ there *exists* a subspace $W_2 \subset V$ such that $V = W_1 \oplus W_2$. You're asking for constraints on $W_1,W_2$ but the point of the question is to show that you can always find a second subspace no matter what is the first subspace.

Comment: The images are from Cohn's *Classic Algebra*.

Comment: @Trancot Btw, this is a standard problem in Linear Algebra and a simple application of the Replacement Theorem. You really shouldn't have to look up a proof for such a question as it follows easily from standard results. Keep that in mind for next time. Cheers.

Comment: @BryanUrízar Cheers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose a basis for $W_1$.  This basis can be extended to a basis for $V$ (well-known result).  Now let $W_2$ be the span of the newly added vectors.  Then
$W_1 \cap W_2 = \{0\}$ by linear independence and $W_1 + W_2 = V$.

Comment: Yes, Jesus, that is precisely what is stated in Cohn's work under the name complement, right?

Comment: Yeah, seems so.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it. Deleted my answer. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set $\mathcal W$ of subspaces $W\subseteq V$ with $W_1\cap W=\{0\}$. Let $W_2$ be a maximal element of $\mathcal W$ (with respect to inclusion). Why does such maximal element exist and why does that solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some explicit examples for you to play around with:

- Let $V$ be 2-dimensional, say $\langle x, y\rangle$, and let $W_1 = \langle x\rangle$. Can you see that $W_2 = \langle y\rangle$ works? Can you see that $\langle x+y\rangle$ also works, and that $\langle 3x - 5y \rangle$ also works, but that $\langle x \rangle$ doesn't, that $\{0\}$ doesn't, and that $\langle x+y, x-y\rangle$ doesn't? (Draw pictures.)
- Let $V = \langle x_1, \dots, x_n\rangle$ (n large), $W_1 = \langle x_1, x_2, x_3\rangle$, and show that $W_2 = \langle x_4, \dots, x_n\rangle$ works.
- Let $V = \langle x, y, z\rangle$, and let $W_1 = \langle x\rangle$. Can you pick the obvious space that works as $W_2$? Can you pick a non-obvious space that works? Can you show why $\langle y\rangle$ and $\langle 3x+5y, x-y\rangle$ don't work?